# Ashot compatibility with Windows zoom

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

When i try to use Ashot to take screenshots of errors on my pc i have a probleme where the images of the website arent taking completly.

What we have when we execute the code :

[image]

What we want :

[image]

When i checked the problem is linked to my computer being 125% and not 100% on the zoom of browsers

[image]

Even though i added the code that i found as a solution on the internet :

```
    Screenshot screenshot = new AShot().shootingStrategy(ShootingStrategies.viewportPasting(ShootingStrategies.scaling(1.25f), 1000)).takeScreenshot(driver);
```

My original code :

```
Screenshot screenshot = new AShot().shootingStrategy(ShootingStrategies.viewportPasting(1000))
                .takeScreenshot(driver);
```

It still doesn't work is there a solution for this probleme ?